# Webpack i18n plugin not working with babel es6

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use the i18n-webpack-plugin alongside babel-loader.

My webpack config:

```
var path        = require("path"),
    I18nPlugin  = require("i18n-webpack-plugin"),
    webpack     = require("webpack"),
    languages   = {
        "en": null,
        "es": require("./src/locale/es.po.json")
    };

module.exports = Object.keys(languages).map(function(language) {
    return {
        name: language,
        entry: {
            home: "./src/static/scripts/script.js",
            alt: "./src/static/scripts/alt.js"
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/static/scripts"),
            filename: language + ".[name].output.js"
        },
        modules: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: ["babel-loader"]
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new I18nPlugin(
                languages[language]
            ),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
        ]
    };
});
```

The error I receive:

```
ERROR in ./src/static/scripts/script.js
    Module parse failed: /Users/anthonydandrea/react/gulp-react-flask/src/static/scripts/script.js Line 1: Unexpected token
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | import React from 'react';
```

Unsure as to what is causing the problem. Seems as though babel is never used and won't let me do the ES6 import on the first line. Note: everything works fine when I comment out the ES6 code.

Comment: Have you tried using Babel in `preLoaders` instead? That plugin is probably adding its loader to run before Babel does.

Comment: Changing `loaders` to `preLoaders` gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Changed 'babel-loader' to 'babel'. Full code below

```
var path        = require("path"),
    I18nPlugin  = require("i18n-webpack-plugin"),
    webpack     = require("webpack"),
    babel = require("babel-loader"),
    languages   = {
        "en": null,
        "es": require("./src/locale/es.po.json")
    };

module.exports = Object.keys(languages).map(function(language) {
    return {
        name: language,
        entry: {
            home: "./src/static/scripts/script.js",
            alt: "./src/static/scripts/alt.js"
        },
        output: {
            path: "./dist/static/scripts",
            filename: language + ".[name].output.js"
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js?$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    loader: 'babel'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new I18nPlugin(
                languages[language]
            ),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
        ]
    };
});
```

Comment: You also changed it from being an array, that is probably the actually issue here.

Comment: Another related question... how is supposed to be loaded that bundled files? I mean, when I generate a js file by language, what is the normal way to load the correct js depending on current language in a website?
Is supposed to be managed in server side or better in client side?
Thanks!

Comment: For me, when a template is served, the backend gives context to what the language needs to be to. Something like `{% if lang == 'es' %}es.bundle.js{% else %}en.bundle.js{% endif %}` is in my template file. If a user changes the language while using it I just send a POST to the backend to change the language and upon success I just do a `location.reload()` to reload the template with the correct bundle file.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'loaders' for array and 'loader' for string.

```
loader: 'babel?someparam!ts'
```

vs.

```
loaders: ['babel?someparam', 'ts']
```